# xamarin uwp : Can't install company app

Tags: xamarin.forms

Dears,

I create my UWP app packages by right click the uwp project -> store -> create app packages option. Go through the steps and 
Then I copy the arm_appxbundle  file from AppPackages folder to my windows phone(8.1). After tapping on that file showing a message like following:

**Can't install company app. There's a problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help.**

In my phone's settings, there is no update and security option for enabling the developer mode.

This app is working fine on my lap, which is windows 10

**Is it possible to install uwp app on windows 8.1?**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP can only run on Windows 10 (and newer). 
If you want to target 8.1, you have to build a 8.1. 
8.1 should run on Windows 10 without any problems.